# Windows 7: How to prevent Windows from caching my desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows, desktop, cache, desktop-customization

I have a service running that renders a changing wallpaper every 5 minutes or so, and replaces the current image file with the new one automatically (That is to say, new image but same filename). On Linux, the change is detected almost automatically, and so I have the most current wallpaper. However, on my Windows 7 machine (Which syncs the image with my Linux machine over Dropbox), it appears to cache the wallpaper from the last time I manually set the wallpaper. The image never changes, even if I restart.

Is there a way to make Windows detect the file change, or periodically refresh the wallpaper cache?
I'd like to avoid third-party apps if at all possible.

Comment: Did you write the service? If so, visit http://stackoverflow.com and ask there, because the service itself has to do this. If not, there probably isn't much you can do (although I won't give a definite answer).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the wallpaper image **copies** it into the windows system folder in XP (and I assume Win 7).  Try changing that copy to a shortcut to the file in your DropBox folder.

Comment: Unforntunately, that doesn't seem to have worked. I can't select the shortcut in Personalize -> Desktop Background -> Browse, and if I right click the shortcut and select Set as Wallpaper, it appears to copy the target instead of the shortcut.

Comment: Then I would say you probably need a piece of software to update the cache. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in this subject and I've found the following:

- If you change the wallpaper from "Explorer" or the "Windows Gallery" then the image is copied to `TrancodedWallpaper.jpg` file in `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`.
- If you change the wallpaper from "IE" then the image is copied to `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Internet Explorer Wallpaper.bmp`.
- If you change the wallpaper from "Firefox", the image is copied to `AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Fondo de escritorio.bmp` (in the Spanish version; I suppose `Desktop Background.bmp` in the English one).

The point is that, if you check `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` you'll get the path to the current desktop, but only if Explorer/Gallery changed it. The IE/FF doesn't change this key but only the desktop.

The key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\Wallpapersource` is the source for your current desktop (for example, one desktop from the `C:\windows\web\wallpaper` folder).

So, it's not true that there is only one location for the wallpaper.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is not a forum -- If you don't have a solution, you should not post an answer. You seem to have another question or follow-up thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you get your service to modify `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg` you may find that’s the live desktop image.